# Issue with extracting a part of absolute path in Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

Can someone please suggest how to extract a portion of the absolute path in Nifi using the UpdateAttribute processor?

For instance, if I have an absolute path like:

```
C:\Users\ram\nifi\E7GW\TC02A\10R140\LC3P-7A511-AE\TempId-01
```

I need to extract the codes `E7GW` , `TC02A` & `10R140`.

In updateAttribute, I created a property and assigned below value to it: `${absolute.path:getDelimitedField(12,'/')}`

But this is just returning the formula that is used. Can someone please help?

Comment: why you are delimiting by `/` when you have windows path delimited by `\ `

Comment: That was a typing mistake. I actually used \. Finally, I was able to extract the codes with the expression: ${absolute.path:getDelimitedField(3,'\\', '"', '~')}